# Difference between "make" and "create"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between these words?

Example:

"How to make something"
"How to create something"

Is there any trick i can use to know which one is the more appropriate for the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One rule of thumb, at least for you as a native speaker of Portuguese, is that English *make* is a quite commonplace word which often works like Portuguese *fazer* or sometimes *preparar* or *construir*, whereas English *create* is a very slightly fancier word that more closely corresponds to Portuguese *criar*.

Try it and see whether that “Lusophonic” trick doesn’t help you out here. You should also be ready to use the English verb *do* in non-auxiliary ways instead of *make*.

Comment: Tenho uma outra dúvida: foi apropriado usar "to know which one" ou eu deveria ter usado "for knowing which one"? Essa é outra questão que me confunde bastante. Se puder responder, eu agradeço. De qualquer forma, te dei a melhor resposta, tá? Obrigado.

Comment: @SeuMadruga Ambas as versões ("trick to know which one" e "trick for knowing which one") funcionam bem neste caso, mas a verdade é que [depende do verbo](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive-vs-gerund?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: I think “trick to know which one” sounds slightly more natural, in this case.

Comment: This is a great answer, but requires specific knowledge of Portuguese. Could you please edit in a description or usecases?

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this that so blatantly do not meet the site standards.

Answer (score 1):

First, "make" and "create" can both mean the same thing when people are speaking offhandedly:

> **make**: to bring into being by forming, shaping, or altering material
>
> **create**: to bring into existence

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make))

but there are some subtle differences when a speaker is trying to be precise.

- If you "create" something, you are making **something that you concieved of or designed yourself**.
- If you merely "make" something, you are fashioning or putting together something **from someone else's design**.

"Make" at the most basic level is a more general word, [from the Old English](https://www.etymonline.com/word/make) verb *macian*,

"create" [entered Middle English much later, in the 14th Century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/create), and usually refers to a special kind of making:

> - to make or bring into existence **something new**
> - to produce through **imaginative skill**
> - **design**

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/create))

The Latin verb *creare*'s path into English isn't entirely clear, but it probably follows a common path of such later borrowings: court French or ecclesiastical Latin, or general snootiness.

*(Etymological info comes from etymonline)*